# Django Sessions via Memcache: Cannot find session key manually

Tags: django, session, caching, memcached, pylibmc

I recently migrated from database backed sessions to sessions stored via memcached using [pylibmc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylibmc).

Here is my CACHES, SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS & SESSION_ENGINE in my settings.py

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
        'LOCATION': ['127.0.0.1:11211'],
    }
}


SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS = 'default'


SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"
```

Everything is working fine behind the scenes and I can see that it is using the new caching system. Running the get_stats() method from pylibmc shows me the number of current items in the cache and I can see that it has gone up by 1.

The issue is I'm unable to grab the session manually using pylibmc.

Upon inspecting the request session data in views.py:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():

        print request.session.session_key
        # the above prints something like this: "1ay2kcv7axb3nu5fwnwoyf85wkwsttz9"

        print request.session.cache_key
        # the above prints something like this: "django.contrib.sessions.cache1ay2kcv7axb3nu5fwnwoyf85wkwsttz9"

        return HttpResponse(status=200)
    else:
        return HttpResponse(status=401)
```

I noticed that when printing cache_key, it prints with the default KEY_PREFIX whereas for session_key it didn't. Take a look at the comments in the code to see what I mean.

So I figured, "Ok great, one of these key names should work. Let me try grabbing the session data manually just for educational purposes":

```
import pylibmc

mc = pylibmc.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'])

# Let's try key "1ay2kcv7axb3nu5fwnwoyf85wkwsttz9"

mc.get("1ay2kcv7axb3nu5fwnwoyf85wkwsttz9")
```

Hmm nothing happens, no key exists by that name. Ok no worries, let's try the cache_key then, that should definitely work right?

```
mc.get("django.contrib.sessions.cache1ay2kcv7axb3nu5fwnwoyf85wkwsttz9")
```

What? How am I still getting nothing back? As I test I decide to set and get a random key value to see if it works and it does. I run get_stats() again just to make sure that the key does exist. I also test the web app to see if indeed my session is working and it does. So this leads me to conclude that there is a different naming scheme that I'm unaware of.

If so, what is the correct naming scheme?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the cache key used internally by Django is, in general, different to the key sent to the cache backend (in this case pylibmc / memcached). Let us call these two keys the django cache key and the final cache key respectively.

The *django cache key* given by `request.session.cache_key` is for use with Django's low-level cache API, e.g.:

```
>>> from django.core.cache import cache
>>> cache.get(request.session.cache_key)
{'_auth_user_hash': '1ay2kcv7axb3nu5fwnwoyf85wkwsttz9', '_auth_user_id': u'1', '_auth_user_backend': u'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'}
```

The *final cache key* on the other hand, is a composition of the [key prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-CACHES-KEY_PREFIX), the django cache key, and the cache [version number](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/#cache-versioning). The `make_key` function (from Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#key-function)) below demonstrates how these three values are composed to generate this key:

```
def make_key(key, key_prefix, version):
    return ':'.join([key_prefix, str(version), key])
```

By default, `key_prefix` is the empty string and `version` is 1.

Finally, by inspecting `make_key` we find that the correct final cache key to pass to `mc.get` is

```
:1:django.contrib.sessions.cache1ay2kcv7axb3nu5fwnwoyf85wkwsttz9
```

which has the form `<KEY_PREFIX>:<VERSION>:<KEY>`.

Note: the final cache key can be changed by defining [`KEY_FUNCTION`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#key-function) in the cache settings.